# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException for seemingly alright script

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am trying to make a simple login page that uses a MySQL database. I receive the following exception:
`java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? and password = md5(?)' at line 1`

When trying to execute the following script:

```
    private static final String FIND_BY_LOGIN_AND_PASSWORD = "select * from user where login = ? and password = md5(?);";
```

This is where the PreparedStatement is created:

```
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(FIND_BY_LOGIN_AND_PASSWORD);
    for (int i = 1; i <= parameters.length; i++) {
        preparedStatement.setObject(i, parameters[i - 1]);
    }
    return preparedStatement;
```

This is where it's used:

```
   ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery(query);
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `executeQuery(query)` is not executing the `PreparedStatement`, it is trying to execute its argument `query` directly (it is a method of `Statement`) - try `execute()` without argument (the method of `PreparedStatement`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71076267/java-sql-sqlsyntaxerrorexception-for-seemingly-alright-script#comment125645007_71076267), you should call [`PreparedStatement#executeQuery`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery()) without any argument. No need for you to pass a query to the execute command, as the prepared statement already contains your query.

```
ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();  // No argument.
```

Comment: Yes, it is working as intended now. What a silly mistake I've made, thanks a lot for the answer